# Resize google map continouosly

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, resize, height

I'm using Google Map Api v3. I set my map div's height with the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var wHeight = $(document).height();
   var mapHeight = wHeight - 120;
   $("#map_canvas").css('height' , mapHeight);
  });
```

I have a top bar div at the top, that's why I subtract 120 pixel and set the map canvas height.
This works fine on page load but I can't get the map to resize when I resize the browser, it stays the same.

I know that there is a resize event in the API:

```
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

I just don't know how to combine that line with the above JQuery to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with the following CSS:

```
#map_canvas { position: absolute; top: 120px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom:0; z-index: 1; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Thanks again Trott. I assume I have to use some javascript with your CSS to get the height of the map to 100%-120px. Just hiding the overflow would be okay, only it cuts off the Google logo and the controls positioned at the bottom of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.resize`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var wHeight = $(document).height();
  var mapHeight = wHeight - 120;
  $("#map_canvas").css('height' , mapHeight);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work for me. I loose my initial height as well. When I try to output the mapHeight var with alert(mapHeight) to check the value nothing happens.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(window).height()` instead of _`document`_?